# Colour Code based on the Colour Name

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working in C#.Net. In a dropdown i should load all the system colours. In the selected index should get the colour code of the selected colour. Here is my code.

```
public void PopulateColourDropDown()
{
    System.Drawing.Color c1 = new System.Drawing.Color();
    Type t = c1.GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p1 in t.GetProperties())
    {
        ColorConverter d = new ColorConverter();
        try
        {
            ddlColour.Items.Add(p1.Name);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In the selected index change, i had given the code like this..

```
 protected void ddlColour_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color c = Color.FromName(ddlColour.SelectedValue);
    string HashCode = Convert.ToString(c.GetHashCode());
    Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(HashCode);
    string colourCode = color.Name;
    TextBox1.BackColor = c;
}
```

But i am not getting the appropriate colour code..

How to get that...

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/af1e0eac-f11e-4b23-a985-bb83e1da90ea/

Answer (score 0):

May you use this: [Color.Fromname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx)

Comment: Its not returning the colour code..Just the Name of the colour and ARGB values...